# How to update/edit IoT Central Cloud Property in IoT Central Application V3?

Tags: azure-iot-central

I am used to setting and defining IoT Central V2 applications.

In V3 application one can define Cloud Properties, general properties that are not supposed to be sent to the device. For example, external data like Last Service Date or Maintenance Organisation are likely to be defined as cloud properties.

But in V3 there doesn´t seem to be any way to update or even enter these values. In V2 one would enter values through a Properties tab and save the values entered. The only option now seems to be to show the (somehow) entered cloud property in an UI view. For a specific device, where do I set/update the cloud properties?

In V2 one could create device properties and update their values directly in the UI of that device.

In V3, I am not able to enter values of any Property fields, even if they are not Cloud Properties. Do I have to set them by the API? Is it not possible to enter Property values in IoT Central? Again, this was possible in V2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spot multiple questions, so I'll focus on the one you set in the title. To edit a cloud property in the V3 of IoT Central, you need to create a View on the device template that allows editing. To do that, you go to the device template, go to Views. Hit "Editing device and cloud data", then you can add the property to a view like so:

[image: Add cloud property to a view]

Hit save, publish the template (requires no migration) and when you visit a device of that template you should see the following:

[image: Editable cloud property]